# Trying to use jsonBuilder on pogo

Tags: json, grails, groovy

I'm using Grails 1.3.4 with Groovy 1.7, and I'm attempting to transform a pogo into json. None of the examples I've seen quite fit my scenario.

```
class NameAndFields {
    String name
    String fields = []
}
```

I'd like to convert NameAndFields into json. Can someone give me an example of this? Do I have to use JsonBuilder?

Comment: I decided to use the jackson ObjectMapper, and now I convert easily between the two formats

Comment: Did you try out the [built-in Grails conversion](http://grails.org/Converters+Reference) functionality?

Comment: JsonBuilder is pretty easy to use, so why would you use the more complex approach of generating xml first, and then converting to JSON?